# 'Field Scraping' in Windows

Tags: c++, screen-scraping, ui-automation

I want to develop an auditing application for certain Windows applications. I want to grab the text from MessageBoxes, Windows, Forms, Selections etc and ideally I would like to program in C++.

I've looked into Windows UI Automation as a possible solution, but am slightly put off as it says it will need to know parts of the underlying data structures which I can't get at. Alternatively, I've looked around and Neo's SafeKeys says that it protects against 'field scraping', but upon searching for it I can't find any information on how it is done. Could someone with experience with this please enlighten me? I'm aware you can scrape websites and the like, but I wish to scrape applications instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the accessibility layer, MSAA

Comment: Looks promising, it looks like what Stu is talking about but as an API. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I presume they are talking about doing a lot of EnumChildWindows() and GetWindowText().

Comment: Ahh I see, and that can 'potentially' get access to every single element in the application?

Comment: If they use actual controls, rather than just drawing fake ones on the main window.

Comment: I see, this will come in handy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this without going near any data structures is to use Abbyy's OCR SDK http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk/ to emulate in an application what their amazing Screenshot reader does. http://www.abbyy.com/screenshot_reader/ . With this technology, nothing you can read on the screen is safe from being captured as text, though it makes a mess of the odd character occasionally.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. Ideally I'd like to stay away from screen capturing software, but nonetheless it's a solution I'll need to consider if there is no other reasonable way of doing it.